# CosmosDB resource is undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I can store documents on Cosmos, no problem. But I cannot retrieve them using the method "read"

```
this.cosmos = new CosmosClient({
  endpoint: ''
  key: ''
});

this.partitionKey = '/id'

this.container = this.cosmos.database('test').container('test');

type Data = {
  value: string;
} & ItemDefinition;

// read it
const { resource } = await this.container.item(key, this.partitionKey).read<Data>();

console.log('>>>', JSON.stringify(resource));
```

Prints `>>> undefined`

What I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE: statusCode is 404, but the object exists on database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Partition Key needs to be the value, not the path.

```
this.partitionKey = '/id'
```

This is the Path.

If you have an item whose id is `A`, then because your Partition Key Path is `/id`, then the Partition Key **Value** is the value of that property in the item, which is also `A`.

```
let key = "A";
let pk = "A";
const { resource } = await this.container.item(key, pk).read<Data>();
```

If your Partition Key Path is, for example, `/someOtherProperty` and you have an item that is:

```
{
  "id": "A",
  "someOtherProperty": "B"
}
```

Then, to read it, you'd do:

```
let key = "A";
let pk = "B";
const { resource } = await this.container.item(key, pk).read<Data>();
```

Comment: Changing the partition key solved the issue. Thank you!